# FB.api post to FB wall from "app page"

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

i got a little problem with facebook javascript api.
I have app and page for this app.
I have added this app to the page and i got "app inside Pages with Like button on the top, you should know".

like here
[image]

Then, using FB.api i'm tried to post message + logo + description + link to the wall on clicking button in this app.
i'm tried to make it looks like this:
[image]

but that's was what i saw after clicking "post to fb" button in my app
[image]

From all properties what i set, it took only "message". Picture was taken from "icon for this app", name was taken from "app page name", another properties were ignored.

code:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',{
    message     :  'Some message',
    link        : 'http://link.com',
    picture     : 'http://link.com/image.jpg',
    name        : 'App name',
    description : 'App description.'
 },
function(response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

i have valid access_token and 'publish_stream' permission, but the same piece of code post
various posts to facebook. result like on the first image from simple app and second image from the page app.

does anyone know how to post to facebook wall messages like on the first image from the app inside page ?

Comment: Do you have Facebook open-graph tags on the page you're trying to link to in the `link` field?

Comment: well, how does they should looks like?

Comment: solved! tomorrow will write how the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post wieving depends from "link" attr in the FB.api method, if it reference to the simple app - post will be like on the first image and if link will reference to the page app - post will look like on the second image.

so as i need result like on the first image - we are just put link to the simple app in the "link" attr and then in the app we will check: "are we on the page app or not, if not - redirect to the app page".